# Why can't I create files larger than 2 GB on Linux?

Tags: linux, files

I wanted to share some knowledge I picked up when I ran into trouble using libpcap and snort to sniff a high-capacity (1 GB full duplex; 2 GB max aggregate) network link. The applications would sniff all traffic successfully, but would crash when the file size hit 2 GB captured.

If you're having issues with creating 2 GB files, even though you have a filesystem that supports it, and/or you know the kernel supports it, this is for you.

Comment: Thought I would share this with the community; let me know if there are any changes I need to make.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Large file support ( >2GB ) for Linux needs to be addressed in three separate locations to ensure you do not run into the 2 GB max file size limit:

1. Large file support enabled in the kernel
2. A filesystem that supports large file sizes (many Linux-based filesystems do (ext3, reiserfs >= 3.6, etc))
3. Large file support within the libraries or applications utilized

Kernel support for large files has been around since 2.4.0-test7; if you use a custom kernel, ensure you've included the large file options.

Most Linux filesystems support large files, but you may have issues using a network file system.

Lastly, libraries (i.e. libpcap) and applications need to be compiled with the gcc options -D _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64. Check to ensure the packages you are using either come precompiled with these options or roll your own.

See [here](http://www.suse.de/~aj/linux_lfs.html) for more details.

Comment: Instead of "FILE_OFFSET_BITS", it should be "_FILE_OFFSET_BITS".

Comment: You're right. Corrected.

Comment: If you downvote, at least be decent and tell me _why_.

Comment: Note: `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` passes `O_LARGEFILE` to the `open` syscall on the correct arch, but 
 `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` is preferred for portability: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888425/is-o-largefile-needed-just-to-write-a-large-file

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a [problem with libpcap](http://lists.virus.org/snort-users-0301/msg00291.html) ... As stated in the first answer.

Recompile libpcap, or find another version.